# Is it possible to connect with infura without a web3 provider?

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract, infura

I am trying to implement fallback funcationality for my DApp which means that when no web3 provider (e.g. metamask/trustwallet etc) is found I can still make calls to the ethereum network but I always seem to get the same issue.

This is my fallback logic:

```
 let bootStrappedWeb3;

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    bootStrappedWeb3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No Web3 Detected... falling back to using default mainnet HTTP Provider');
    bootStrappedWeb3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<MY_API_KEY>"));
  }
  window.web3 = bootStrappedWeb3;

  // Listen for when web3 is connected and then bootstrap the app
  window.web3.eth.net.isListening()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('is connected');

      // Bootstrap the full app
      this.$store.dispatch(actions.INIT_APP, bootStrappedWeb3);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Something went wrong', e));
```

I see `is connected` and then `INIT_APP` is called.

`INIT_APP` then sets the provider on my truffle contract like this:

`MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);`

I can correctly read the current network which reports as on `Mainnet`, ID 1, but then whenever I try to use truffle this then falls over.

The call to truffle looks like this:

```
 MyContract.deployed()
    .then((contract) => {
      // Do stuff 
    }).catch((error) => console.log("Something went bang!", error));
```

An exception is throw and I ass the error which is as follows:

```
Something went bang! TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Provider.sendAsync (contract.js?6b6f:24)
at RequestManager.sendAsync (requestmanager.js?e4d9:80)
at Object.get [as getNetwork] (property.js?7a8c:116)
at eval (contract.js?6b6f:512)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.detectNetwork (contract.js?6b6f:503)
at Function.deployed (contract.js?6b6f:451)
at Store.eval (index.js?e3b1:444)
at Array.wrappedActionHandler (vuex.esm.js?edaa:704)
at Store.dispatch (vuex.esm.js?edaa:426)
at boundDispatch (vuex.esm.js?edaa:332)
at eval (index.js?e3b1:273)
at tryCatcher (bluebird.js?e531:5063)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (bluebird.js?e531:3095)
at Promise._settlePromise (bluebird.js?e531:3153)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (bluebird.js?e531:3198)
at Promise._settlePromises (bluebird.js?e531:3281)
at eval (bluebird.js?e531:162)
at MutationObserver.eval (bluebird.js?e531:4330)
```

Has anyone got any ideas? From the documentation and examples I have read I believe this should work, and and all help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Ive found this which kind of looks similar https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/pull/50

Comment: After trying out the suggest fix/hack on the above truffle issue it does fix my issue, not ideal
e.g. change contract.js 
Provider.prototype.sendAsync = function() {
    if (this.provider.sendAsync != null) {
      return this.provider.sendAsync.apply(this.provider, arguments);
    } 
    return this.provider.send.apply(this.provider, arguments);
  };

Comment: the work around fixes it for now https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the described work around on this ticket solved the problem for me: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57

e.g

```
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
if (typeof MyContract.currentProvider.sendAsync !== "function") {
     MyContract.currentProvider.sendAsync = function() {
        return MyContract.currentProvider.send.apply(
            MyContract.currentProvider, arguments
        );
    };
}
```